# how do I import jquery.datatable.bootstrap in application.scss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since scss uses @import in place of require. what can be done to import jquery datatable. I want to add the below code in application.scss file

```
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

This is the application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at the source code to figure out if you can do this.

Just because a gem provides assets that can be required by the Rails asset pipeline, doesn't mean that it's written in SASS. The `@import` is specific to SASS and had to do with building the compiled CSS.

If you look at look at your `application.scss` when compiled, you'll see your bootstrap mixins as CSS. This is SASS loading the file content and is separate from the Rails asset pipeline.

I would say do not change this… I've used the SASS bootstrap gem and JQuery.DataTable Rails gem together using the described setup.

Because the imports for bootstrap is specific for the library (for example provisioning the colour sets to bootstraps elements), while the `*= require` has to do with the if's and how's of serving the asset publicly to the web.

The reason your bootstrap mixins are being included into your application is because of `require_self`.